# Display loading gif with jQuery-ui autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui, datatables, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using **jQuery-ui autocomplete version v1.12.1**. How do I add loading GIF ? I am trying to retrive data using jQuery only ... There is NO AJAX call.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var product_data = <?php echo $product_implode; ?>;
        if(product_data != ''){
            jQuery( "#search_box" ).autocomplete({
                appendTo: "#project-description",
                minLength: 1,
                source: product_data,
                open: function(e, ui) {
                    jQuery('#project-description').addClass('autocomplete-content');
                },
                close: function(e, ui){
                    jQuery('#project-description').removeClass('autocomplete-content');
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Here is my code for autocomplete. And I am using **datatables version 1.10.16** to display data. I want to show loader image until search data is not displayed.

Comment: Your request is unclear. What GIF do you want to have shown? Where? If there is no AJAX Call, then data would appear right away. Do you want to add a delay and show the loading gif at that time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JQuery autocomplete adds the `ui-autocomplete-loading` class at the time of loading content.

Add the following line to css:

```
.ui-autocomplete-loading { background:url(http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif) no-repeat right center }
```

**Edit:**

As said by @Twisty, if you have your all data at client side, then it will not get enough time to display loading gif while displaying autocomplete.

So you can add following script with css above mentioned. See [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yashsoni789/mnfe3dby/4/)

```
setTimeout(function(){
    //logic of fetching data.
}, 1500);
```

Hope, this may help you to solve your problem.